# Getting Mage in the link of image in Product View Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, css, image

I have created a custom theme and placed an image in the theme's web/images folder i.e `web/images/abc.png`

I have used this image in the css as `background: url("../images/abc.png");`

Image show in background on all pages expect `product view page` by running command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

After inspecting in product view page git this link of image with and additional mage folder in the link ,dont know where this 
 mage is coming from https://dev.uncleharrys.com/static/version1504805844/frontend/UncleHarrys/Extended/en_US/mage/images/cart_icon.png

whereas it has to be
https://dev.uncleharrys.com/static/version1504805844/frontend/UncleHarrys/Extended/en_US/images/cart_icon.png

How to fix?